# Ambiguous type for polymorphic function members of driver GADT

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, gadt

I'm testing some code for a little experiment I'm doing but right at the beginning I've hit a roadblock that I don't see how to fix.

```
data DatabaseDriver a b where
  DatabaseDriver :: (Table table, Field field) =>  {
      dbInsert :: table -> [field] -> String
    , dbSelect :: table -> [field] -> String
    } -> DatabaseDriver a b

class Table a where
    tableName :: a -> String

class Field a where
    fieldName :: a -> String
    fieldValue :: a -> String

psqlDriver = DatabaseDriver insert select
    where
        insert t fs = "insert into " ++ tableName t ++ " (" ++ fieldNames fs ++ ") values (" ++ fieldValues fs ++ ")"
        select t fs = "select " ++ fieldNames fs ++ " from " ++ tableName t
        fieldNames = joinComma fieldName
        fieldValues = joinComma fieldValue
        joinComma f = foldl (\a n -> a ++ ", " ++ n) "" . map f
```

Ok, so this is some test code, the driver functions would get much more complicated than this but even in this test I get the error "Ambiguous type variable 'a0' in the constraint: (Field a0) arising from a use of `fieldName'.  So the compiler does see that fieldName is applied to a field but apparently it wants a more concrete type here.  I guess having the functions remain polymorphic makes pgsqlDriver not a concrete class?

But the idea would be that these functions are polymorphic.  That's the reason I chose to use a GADT here, so I could put type constraints on the parameters to these driver functions without having to repeat them in every instantiation.  The plan would be that the defined database driver could work with any Field and Table instances.  Can this simply not be done and my DatabaseDriver type would also have to be a type class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options here.  The first option is to add

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

to the top of your module file.

The second option is to add an explicit type signature to psqlDriver.

```
psqlDriver :: (Field field, Table table) => (table -> [field] -> String) -> DatabaseDriver a b
```

The reason for all of this is a little nuanced, and more details can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

The third option is to change the definition of `psqlDriver` to

```
psqlDriver = DatabaseDriver insert select
```

However, this is truly ambiguous - there is not reason to prefer any particular instance of `Table` or `Field` over another.  Perhaps you mean to define `DatabaseDriver` as follows.

```
data DatabaseDriver table field where
  DatabaseDriver :: (Table table, Field field) =>  {
      dbInsert :: table -> [field] -> String
    , dbSelect :: table -> [field] -> String
    } -> DatabaseDriver table field
```

If the original definition of `DatabaseDriver` is rewritten as an ADT, it is more obvious why.

As it is currently written in the question, the translation to an ADT is

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data DatabaseDriver a b
  = forall table field .
    (Table table, Field field) => DatabaseDriver
    { dbInsert :: table -> [field] -> String
    , dbSelect :: table -> [field] -> String
    }
```

Notice the nested `forall table field`, and how `table` and `field` have no relationship to `a` or `b`.

The intended translation is either

```
data DatabaseDriver table field
  = (Table table, Field field) => DatabaseDriver
    { dbInsert :: table -> [field] -> String
    , dbSelect :: table -> [field] -> String
    }
```

or most likely

```
data DatabaseDriver table field
  = DatabaseDriver
    { dbInsert :: table -> [field] -> String
    , dbSelect :: table -> [field] -> String
    }
```

Having the type class constraints in the definition of `DatabaseDriver` does not let you remove the type class constraints from any use of `DatabaseDriver`, in particular `psqlDriver`.  In both of the ADT translations above, the type of `psqlDriver` is

```
psqlDriver :: (Table table, Field field) => DatabaseDriver table field
```

Comment: Neither of these appear to work for me.  The No mono restrictions pragma does clean up the errors some but it still shows an error on the definition and added a signature doesn't clean that up.

But I notice that you give a signature of a function while psqlDriver is actually just a record.

I suspect records can't have polymorphic functions because that would make them "polymorphic" which doesn't make sense (I guess?) for a data type.

Comment: As currently written, `psqlDriver` is not a record, but instead a function.  It still requires a second argument, `dbSelect`.  Records can definitely be polymorphic.  If you want `psqlDriver` to be of type  `forall a b . DatabaseDriver a b`, you will need to provide a second argument, possibly named `select` (though this name does not matter, and I only choose this name because of the current name for the first argument `insert`).

Comment: I now see what was intended and have modified the answer.

Comment: Oh dear, actually I meant to have select defined (notice the function is defined in the where clause, just not used in the top level statement) and it is in my code.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If the purpose of the `a` and `b` type parameters in `DatabaseDriver a b` is to allow for any instance of `Table` and any instance of `Field`, then the third option should be your solution.  I will edit the third option further to explain why.